# Spring storing some data in session or flash storage

Tags: java, spring, session, storage

I am new to spring. I would like to store some small data. F.e:

- filled form data/object in case that User put in form some incorrect data (just for one post/get action)
- some short messages like: "You 've logged out succeffuly", or "You have submited correct data" (just for one post/get action)
- user sessions information like: date of login, id, email, name, roles and permission.

How can I achive this?

Answer (score 0):

In general for storing information across sessions you need to look into Session Attributes (@SessionAttribute), you can also use Flash for controllers that are doing redirects.

Here is a good tutorial and explanation on Session Attributes http://www.intertech.com/Blog/understanding-spring-mvc-model-and-session-attributes/

But for points 1 and 3 i wouldn't recommend using session attribute:

Point 1: Call the same view because the object you are validating is same thus you can also add the error messages. Less coding and complexity for more.

Point 3: Some of this information is already stored as part of security context, although minimal information. I personally pull username and then get the object from db to get the whole user object.

If you plan on doing a lot of back and forth with pages and share objects best bet is to use spring webflows.

Hope that helps.